# small numbers in CalendarView android

Tags: android, calendar

I need the CalendarView for my app. But the numbers of the days are very small. How to make them bigger?

[image: CalendarView]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, it's a bug in the code for the CalendarView. Here's a reference to the bug. It's not a real answer, but more of an explanation, I guess.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34932

Allegedly, it's been fixed in 4.2.

Answer (score 6):

If someone's still interested, here's my solution based on the info provided in Phil's post and on the report from XSJoJo. As mentioned there, the problem is present because the `mDateTextSize` isn't assigned to the `mMonthNumDrawPaint` in the `CalendarViewLegacyDelegate`. I'm using Java reflection.

```
    /**
     * I'm doing this in my fragment's onCreateView() callback
     */

    CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_view);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) { // this bug exists only in Android 4.1
        try {
            Object object = calendarView;
            Field[] fields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : fields) {
                if (field.getName().equals("mDelegate")) { // the CalendarViewLegacyDelegate instance is stored in this variable
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    object = field.get(object);

                    break;
                }
            }

            Field field = object.getClass().getDeclaredField("mDateTextSize"); // text size integer value
            field.setAccessible(true);
            final int mDateTextSize = (Integer) field.get(object);

            field = object.getClass().getDeclaredField("mListView"); // main ListView
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object innerObject = field.get(object);

            Method method = innerObject.getClass().getMethod(
                    "setOnHierarchyChangeListener", ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener.class); // we need to set the OnHierarchyChangeListener
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(innerObject, (Object) new ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildViewAdded(View parent, View child) { // apply text size every time when a new child view is added
                    try {
                        Object object = child;
                        Field[] fields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
                        for (Field field : fields) {
                            if (field.getName().equals("mMonthNumDrawPaint")) { // the paint is stored inside the view
                                field.setAccessible(true);
                                object = field.get(object);
                                Method method = object.getClass().
                                        getDeclaredMethod("setTextSize", float.class); // finally set text size
                                method.setAccessible(true);
                                method.invoke(object, (Object) mDateTextSize);

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(APP_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildViewRemoved(View parent, View child) {}
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(APP_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```