# Android CalendarView text size too small on 4.1

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, calendarview

It looks like there is a bug with Jelly Bean 4.1 that causes the text size of dates in `CalendarView` to be disproportionally small on hi-res devices. Appears that it is fixed in 4.2, but is there any workaround to make it look sensible on 4.1 devices?

I tried something like this:

```
<CalendarView android:dateTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />
```

but no change.

[Screenshot jellybean 4.1 http://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=349320000000&name=date_too_small_gn.png&token=oky3Ymwfjqtj-Q2b1E1zi8ZEhMw%3A1366750079333&inline=1](http://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=349320000000&name=date_too_small_gn.png&token=oky3Ymwfjqtj-Q2b1E1zi8ZEhMw%3A1366750079333&inline=1)

Comment: Have tried overriding that text size for only the api version that is affected?

Comment: You might want to take a look at my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36321828/3185295