# Android CalendarView date text appearance font size

Tags: android, android-styles, calendarview

Apparently many people have had this problem and no one seems to know the correct solution.  I'm using the CalendarView widget but the text size of the dates are too small.

[Android CalendarView text size too small on 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179072/android-calendarview-text-size-too-small-on-4-1)
No solution found.

[Android calendarview font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412549/android-calendarview-font-size)
Again, no solution found.

```
<style name="Widget.CalendarView.Custom" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:weekDayTextAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
        <item name="android:dateTextAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Large</item>
        <item name="android:weekNumberColor">@color/titlebackgroundcolor</item>
</style>
```

This is from my styles.xml file.  It appears that no matter what I change here (other than the parent theme) nothing actually changes in the layout.  I am using Jelly Bean, but targeting any other API provides no solution either.

I've tried skipping styles altogether and using the `calendar.setDateTextAppearance` method which required me to Target a different API.  Still didn't work.  It seems I have tried everything.  Has anyone found a way to fix this issue?  If I can avoid having to use an entirely different way to display a calendar I would rather do that, but if not, please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: So, no one has any idea what to do here?  Aside from using a different calendar altogether?

Comment: Here's my workaround using Java reflection API:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/36321828/3185295